# not able to print value selecting from Modal in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have created an application where I have to select a data from modal and get result printed in the paragraph.

The below link will help to understand the functionality

https://jsfiddle.net/2empvtas/3/

Modal gets loaded and the result gets printed but both the values get printed instead of the selected value. b

**HTML CODE**

```
   <p> Result will apper here
<span class='add-tax'></span>
</p>
<button class='w3-btn w3-ripple w3-blue-grey w3-round' onclick='document.getElementById("tax").style.display="block"' href=''>Add data rate</button>


<div id="tax" class='w3-modal w3-small w3-round' id='tax_modal'>
    <div class='w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4 w3-round' style='width:50%'>
      <header class='w3-container w3-blue-grey'> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('tax').style.display='none'"
        class='w3-button w3-display-topright'>&times;</span><br>
        <h5>Action Required</h5>
      </header>
      <div class='w3-container'>
        <h5>Data List</h5>
 <table class="w3-table w3-responsible">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>abc</th>
              <td class='tax'>
                <p class='add_tax'>
                  1
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>efg</th>
              <td class='tax'>
                <p class='add_tax'>
                  2
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
           </div>
       <footer class='w3-container w3-blue-grey'> 
        <br>
       <button onclick='document.getElementById("tax").style.display="none"' class='w3-round w3-button w3-blue w3-hover-pale-blue'>Cancel</button>
        <a style='text-decoration:none;' class='w3-round w3-button w3-red w3-hover-pale-red' href='#'>Delete</a>
        <br><br>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**jquery code**

```
$(".add_tax").click(function(){
    //console.log("done done");
    //var tax;var result;
    $('.add_tax').each(function(){
        tax = $('.add_tax').text();
        $('.add-tax').text(tax); 
       console.log("1"+tax);
       document.getElementById('tax').style.display = 'none';
    });
    //$('.add-tax').text(tax); 
   //$("#tax_modal").remove();

    /*
    var tax = $('.add_tax').text();
        console.log(tax);
    $('.add-tax').text($('.add_tax').val()); 
    $("#tax_modal").hide();*/
});
```

Comment: Where is `add_tax` in your HTML code?

Comment: I have made the changes.

Comment: Ok, @Jasshh, I have posted my answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your jquery code like this:

```
$(".add_tax").click(function(){
    tax = $(this).text();
    $('.add-tax').text(tax);
    document.getElementById('tax').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Notice that I have removed `.each` function. Because `.each` will iterate through all `.add_tax` classes and take its text. Which we did not want.

Comment: Your welcome @JasshhAndrews, happy to help. Thank you for accepting and up voting my answer.